# Unfamiliar symbol [=] in C++

Tags: c++, templates, sfml

I am working on a game using SFML going through some tutorials when I ran into a line of code that I have never scene. The full thing is at [SFML Game Development](https://github.com/SFML/SFML-Game-Development-Book/blob/master/05_States/Include/Book/Command.hpp) but the specific symbol was [=] and here is a simplified form of the code.

```
template <typename data_type, typename Function>
std::function<void(data_type1&)> foo(Function x)
{
    return [=] (data_type1 y)
    {
        DoSomething(y);
    };
}
```

I think I get the point of the code but what is the significance of the brackets around an equal sign? I did not find mention of it on any website unless I just used poor search terms.

Comment: Look up about _lambda expression_.

Comment: Take a look at this: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The square brackets indicate the capture terms for the lambda function.  If you put `=` in it, that indicates automatic capture (by value) of all symbols used in the lambda.  Capture means that those variables are available for use in the lambda, without being function parameters.

Let's say you were using the variable `x` that was passed into `foo` inside the lambda.  Then the value of `x` would automatically be captured in the lambda, and made accessible by the same name.  A more explicit way would be to indicate that `x` is to be captured:

```
[x] (data_type1 y)
{
    DoSomethingElse(x, y);
};
```

In your case it doesn't have any effect because there are no such symbols.  More likely, it's a sloppy programming practice that has been adopted by whoever wrote it.  Or there are times when it is required, and this is a copy-paste hangover.

I should add that this might be used if `foo` and `DoSomething` are actually methods in a class.  In that case, the `=` would automatically capture `this`, and resolve to the correct call to `DoSomething`

Comment: Perfect. The way the search engines work and strip the characters down so it wouldn't even let me search on this site and yet already somebody has tagged it as a duplicate question.